# Sencha touch 2 application not working on android mobile version 4

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to run sencha app on android mobile with api level 15 to support application from version 4. It is not going to the home screen,it's stuck at the loading screen only. It works perfectly on api level 17(4.2.2)/18(4.3). I have installed android sdk for api level 14(4),15(4.0.3). I am using sencha touch 2.2.1 and Sencha Cmd 3.1.2.342.

Any possible reason for this behavior , or have I missed any thing please help.

Comment: Post your logcat errors

Comment: I cant see any error log , i m running on device through terminal.help me getting logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your JS debugging console for errors? Apps stuck at the loading screen typically have encountered a runtime error.

Comment: I am running it on device through mac terminal(command prompt). Can you explain how to check that.There is no error in the terminal though.

Comment: See this link: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: There is not much help there either. I am still not able to run 4.0.4 or below android os. I even tried installing the apk file still it does not run on the the device with version lower than 4.1.